How does the CDF II $W$ boson mass measurement position itself relative to previous measurements?
The paper High-precision measurement of the W boson mass with the CDF II detector compares their results to the results of previous measurements in Fig. 5. While they show this visual comparison, there seems to be no statement about the statistical (dis)agreement of the CDF II measurement with previous measurements, e.g., ATLAS. The CDF II measurement is reported to disagree with the Standard Model at $7.0\sigma$ but what if, for example, the disagreement between CDF II and ATLAS (and perhaps other previous measurements) would be $>5\sigma$, too? What would that mean?

From: CDF Collaboration†‡ et al., High-precision measurement of the W boson mass with the CDF II detector. Science 376, 170-176 (2022). DOI: 10.1126/science.abk1781
